# Dynamically adding form input field by clicking on add button

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to make a party hosting app in ionic 2. Now I want to dynamically add form input field for guests by clicking on add button. Any idea how to do it in ionic2 with angular2? On clicking add I want three fields to appear: name, mailId, contact.

Answer (score 0):

you can using formGroup and FormCOntrol :
by when the user click on add button show the html and add the three form Controller by using this : 
  this.yourForm.addControl('nameOfControl', new FormControl("", Validators.required));
and delete them when hide :
this.yourForm.removeControl('nameOfControl');